# What publications or institutions govern proper usage of the Russian language?

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление

Some of the questions I’ve asked in other posts might come across as a bit picayune.  Some of these questions involve observations of what might entail elective variance between written rules of usage for the Russian language and actual usage.  How are situations like this settled when it comes to professional translation where egos and different experiences and levels of education might be involved?

Does this really just depend on who is doing the translation (e.g., the in-house rules for a translation company)?

Are there any standard, reputable publications or institutions of authority that translators or linguists and teachers of the Russian language typically turn to over points of contention on usage?  For example, the Spanish have the [**Real Academia Española**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Academia_Espa%C3%B1ola) (an institution that serves as an authority on matters pertaining to the Spanish language).  Does the Russian language have anything similar to this?

Comment: As for the publications, see my answer to this question: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14098

Comment: @shabunc, I don't think this question is a duplicate. The question you link to asks about "state organizations promoting Russian abroad". This question is about "institutions of authority" that "govern proper usage of Russian". One such institution is undoubtedly the Russian Language Institute: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Language_Institute. One of its products is _Русская грамматика_ which describes and codifies the language: http://lukashevichus.info/knigi/russk_gramm_sl_shvedova_1.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/273

Comment: The thread at [**"Does “official Russian” language exist?"**](https://goo.gl/V4A9kp) is much more in line with the information I was hoping to find.  I can see why it could be considered a duplicate of [**"Is there a Russian analogue of British Council or Goethe-Institut?"**](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/272/is-there-a-russian-analogue-of-british-council-or-goethe-institut) but the Real Academia Española, as can be inferred by Sergey Slepov's comment, appears to be more focused on activities involved with governing the language and not promoting it.

Comment: Spain does have other organizations that might be similar to the British Council or the Goethe-Institut ... the [**Cervantes Institute**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instituto_Cervantes) may be their best Spanish equivalent.

Comment: As far as this being an exact duplicate, of [**"Does 'official Russian' language exist?"**](https://goo.gl/V4A9kp) I suppose you could make a case for that.  Oddly enough, in the search I always do before posting, this post did not come up.  (It makes me wonder how it has been tagged.)  If I had seen it earlier, I might not have asked it.  Still, the title of it is somewhat vague and I was hoping either post would have yielded/would yield more feedback/insight from Russian translators/interpreters.  But you're the boss, @shabunc.  However, you want to handle this is fine with me.